# How get header data from nsIMsgDBHdr in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email-headers, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to get a custom message from the [nsIMsgDBHdr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIMsgDBHdr) interface.

```
let result = msgHdr.getProperty('x-custom');
```

But `result` is empty.

I tried to register headers in the [preferences](https://kewisch.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/executing-js-code-when-receiving-an-email-with-a-specific-header-set/) but this has no effect.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Solved issue.

```
Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/Services.jsm");
let pref = "mailnews.customDBHeaders";
let chNames = ['x-custom', 'x-custom-2'];
// Save preferences.
Services.prefs.setCharPref(pref, chNames.join(" ").trim());
```

Get custom headers via nsIMsgDBHdr:

```
msgHdr.getStringProperty('x-custom');
```

Custom headers will appear only in new messages. In order that they appear in all the emails - it is necessary to re-index database.